# fastapi, pymongo not querying lookup and returns empty on response

Tags: python, pymongo, fastapi

I have a simply query, find the user in user collection from group collection.
It is returning empty.

Problem 1:
"user" is empty.

Problem 2: Response is completely empty `[]` in postman.

```
query = group.collection.aggregate([
            { '$match':  {"usersId: {"$in": [ ObjectID('some id') ] }} },
            {
                "$lookup":
                {
                    "from": "user",
                    "localField": "usersId",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "user"
                }
            },
            {
                '$project': {
                    '_id': 0,
                    'createdAt': 1,
                    'updatedAt': 1,
                    'user.name' :1
                }
            }
            ])
        print (json.dumps(list(query), default=str)) # prints the data but user is empty

        return  JSONResponse(
                    status_code=200,
                    content=loads(dumps(list(query))) # returns []
                )
```

This is what it prints.

```
[{ "createdAt": 1679081594322, "updatedAt": 1679081594322, "user": []}, 
 { "createdAt": 1679083049799, "updatedAt": 1679083049799, "user": []} ]
```

Comment: Is `usersId` a list or just one ObjectId?

Comment: @Er... it's a list

Comment: i also tried `'user': { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT.user" }`

Comment: If your mongo version may be old, check that you can `$lookup` over arrays. Otherwise... Is your `$match` stage returning anything?